# In a function ,How can I assign the value to a set?

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to make a program that finds the perfect number.(Perfect number=The sum of its divisors except itself is a number equal to itself.)And I want to add one more thing. Firstly I want to define an empty list and put the perfect numbers in it.But When I run the programm I didn't take the right throughput.How can I solve this problem.

My cods

```
def perfect(number): 
    total = 0
    for i in range(1,number):
        if number % i == 0:
            total += i
    return total

perfect_number_set = []
for i in range(1,1001)
    if perfect(i):
        perfect_number_set += [perfect(i)]
        print(perfect_number_set)
        print(i)
```

The output of the codes I wrote

```
[True]
6
[True,True]
28
[True,True,True]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If you want to add values to a set, use a set, not a list.

Comment: `if perfect(i):` what does this line mean?

Comment: @Tuqay i meant if i was the perfect number

Comment: @mkrieger Sorry I use wrong word.The right word is list,not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have following issues in your code:

1. Your implementation of `perfect` method is incorrect. You need to return `True`/`False` if a number is `perfect`. You are returning the total which is not correct.
2. Missing colon `:` in the `for` loop

```
def perfect(number): 
    total = 0
    for i in range(1,number):
        if number % i == 0:
            total += i
    return total == number
    
perfect_number_list = []
for i in range(1,1001):
    if perfect(i):
        print(i)
        perfect_number_list.append(i)
print(perfect_number_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference between set and a list in python. You have used a list.
Set contains only unique entries.

Best practice tip:
defining a list use :

```
list_name = list()
```

Better way of adding items to as list by using it's method

```
list_name.append(list_item_to_add)
```

Another thing is that returning a number and checking it in if without any condition is not readable. Change it to:

```
if perfect(i) != 0:
```

(Altho Yours implementation work, because python if treats 0 like False and any other value as True)